# Installing Texmaker on KDE Neon - qtbase-abi-5-9-5 has no installation candidate

Tags: texmaker, ubuntu, dependencies

I have tried to install Texmaker on KDE Neon. In Discover it says: Dependency resolution failed. In Terminal I have tried this:

```
mangodile@Mangodile:~$ sudo apt-get install texmaker
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 1
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 1
Investigating (0) texmaker:amd64 < none -> 5.0.2-1build2 @un puN Ib >
Broken texmaker:amd64 Depends on qtbase-abi-5-9-5:amd64 < none @un H >
Considering libqt5core5a:amd64 2948 as a solution to texmaker:amd64 9999
Broken texmaker:amd64 Depends on texmaker-data:amd64 < none | 5.0.2-1build2 @un uH > (= 5.0.2-1build2)
Considering texmaker-data:amd64 0 as a solution to texmaker:amd64 9999
Re-Instated texmaker-data:amd64
Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
texmaker : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-9-5
        Recommends: psutils
        Recommends: latex-beamer but it is not installable
        Recommends: texlive-latex-extra but it is not going to be   installed
        Recommends: texlive-lang-english but it is not going to be installed
        Recommends: asymptote but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
mangodile@Mangodile:~$ sudo apt-get install qtbase-abi-5-9-5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package qtbase-abi-5-9-5 is a virtual package provided by:
       libqt5core5a 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1 [Not candidate version]

E: Package 'qtbase-abi-5-9-5' has no installation candidate
mangodile@Mangodile:~$ sudo apt-get install libqt5core5a
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libqt5core5a is already the newest version (5.11.2+dfsg-    0xneon+18.04+bionic+build46).
libqt5core5a set to manually installed.
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer    required:
 discover discover-data libdiscover2 libusb-0.1-4
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I also have to note that I am new in Linux.

Edit: I forgot to try download it on official Texmaker website. Same problem.

Comment: Try to install `libqt5core` or similar.

Comment: Tried, but it had some dependecies and I installed libqt5qui and I had to reinstall KDE Neon

Comment: It's a bug in KDE Neon. You have to recompile the package with the new ABI. You can use `apt-get source` and `dpkg-buildpackage` for that, if you're familiar with Debian packaging.

Answer (score 2):

Ran into a similar issue, there is an problem with the debian package and KDE Neon, you need to edit it :

1. [Download the .deb package on the texmaker website](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html)
2. Uncompress it by using `ar -x tex_$YOUR_VERSION$.deb` (you will need `binutils` for that)
3. Uncompress the `control` file : `tar xf control.tar.xz`
4. Edit it and remove the `qtbase-abi-5-9-5` dependency
5. Recompress the `content` file : `tar cfJ control.tar.xz control`
6. Rebuld the .deb file : `ar rcs $Package_name$ debian-binary control.tar.xz data.tar.xz`
7. Install it with dpkg

Comment: That might sove the problem, but note in general that `qtbase-abi-5-9-5` is added as a dependency if the package rely exactly on the qt version 5.9.5 due to special calls. That means that the package will not work if the specific version of qt is not available (segfault or similar). Usually KDE Neon ships newer versions of qt and this is why packages fail to install.